# Angular 6 - Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'http' in

Tags: angular, angular6, tin-can-api

I am trying to work with TinCanJS library in angular 6

[github project](https://github.com/RusticiSoftware/TinCanJS)

I installed the package using `npm install tincanjs --save`

I imported the files in angular.json as follow:

```
"scripts": [
              "./node_modules/tincanjs/node_modules/xhr2/lib/xhr2.js",
              "./node_modules/tincanjs/build/tincan-min.js"
            ]
```

I also tried as follow:

```
"scripts": [
    "./node_modules/xhr2/lib/xhr2.js",
    "./node_modules/tincanjs/build/tincan-min.js"
]
```

In my app component I imported the tincan library as plain javascript because it has not type script as follow:

```
import * as TinCan from 'tincanjs';
```

When I build the project using `ng serve` I keep getting the following error:

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/tincanjs/node_modules/xhr2/lib/xhr2.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'http' in 'C:\Dev Projects\xAPI Angular Example\xAPIExample\node_modules\tincanjs\node_modules\xhr2\lib'
ERROR in ./node_modules/tincanjs/node_modules/xhr2/lib/xhr2.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'https' in 'C:\Dev Projects\xAPI Angular Example\xAPIExample\node_modules\tincanjs\node_modules\xhr2\lib'
ERROR in ./node_modules/tincanjs/node_modules/xhr2/lib/xhr2.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'os' in 'C:\Dev Projects\xAPI Angular Example\xAPIExample\node_modules\tincanjs\node_modules\xhr2\lib'
```

The TincanJS libarary has a dependency on the xhr2. I have checked the physical folder and the xhr2.js file exists in the right location.

I was wondering what am i doing wrong?
Can you help

Comment: did you include `tincanjs` in your **angular.json**?

Comment: @JohnVelasquez yes I did

Comment: @JohnVelasquez Please look at the question again, i have updated it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove the `xhr2`

it should be,

```
"scripts": [
    "node_modules/tincanjs/build/tincan-min.js"
]
```

For declaration, instead of

```
import * as TinCan from 'tincanjs';
```

use

```
declare const TinCan: any;
```

Comment: I did it, but it still looks for the file within \node_modules\tincanjs\node_modules\xhr2\lib... and not under the root node_modules

Comment: could you try `tincan.js` instead of `tincan-min.js`

Comment: Any ideas fixing it?

Comment: Yes, it worked :) why can't I use the import approach?

Comment: for me its better that way, because `tincanjs` is plain js and doesn't have `@types` in the npm, and I would like to recommend you to download `TSLint` extension if you're using **vscode**, in the ide you can see the error

Comment: I do have TSLint